# Swift Results not updating with SearchBar added through Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a perfectly working `SearchController` that is currently placed at the top of `tableView` as such

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

However I want to put a `searchBar` to always stay on top of `tableView`, even when scrolling. I added it through storyboard and it shows up but it doesn't work properly, the results are not updating when I'm typing into the `mySearch`
My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySearch: UISearchBar!

func configureSearchController(){
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for songs"
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = GlobalSettings.tint.color
    searchController.searchBar.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal

    mySearch = searchController.searchBar
}
```

How do I properly connect `@IBOutlet searchBar` to `searchController`?

Comment: I added a UIView through storyboard and added searchController.searchBar as its subview `searchView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)` and it works but it still would be great if there was a simpler solutions so the question will stay opened

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your outlet from `UISearchBar` to `UISearchController` ?
If I'm not mistaken, it does work with a UISearchBar in Storyboard.

Here is updated code :

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySearch: UISearchController!

func configureSearchController(){
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for songs"
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = GlobalSettings.tint.color
        searchController.searchBar.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
        searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    }
```